# jquery events: (sometimes) handle two events at the same time

Tags: jquery

I have two controls on my page. A textbox and a radiobutton. Both of them fire an event and those get handled. In each handle, data from the control is used to call a rest-service.

In pseudo-code:

```
If textbox has focus lost -> call restText(textbox.value)
If radiobutton is clicked -> call restRadio(radiobutton.value)
```

So far, so good. The requirement now is that if the radio is clicked and the textbox looses focus at the same time, it should react like that:

```
If radiobutton is clicked && textbox has focus lost **before** -> call restBoth(radiobutton.value, textbox.value)
```

Well, the keyword **before** is my issue. How can I handle both events at the same time and not have the textbox focus lost prior to the radiobutton?

Comment: Nothing yet. I have no clue how to "ignore" the textbox event if a radio is clicked. Focus lost always fires and the ajax returns with a new content rendering, which kinda "shadows" the radio event ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form name='emailSubmit' action='' method='post'>
    <input type='text' id='email' value='I am text :)' />
    <input type='radio' name='accept'  /> I am radio 1 :)
     <input type='radio' name='accept'  /> I am radio 2 :)
     <input type='radio' name='accept'  /> I am radio 3 :)
</form>
```

> Your Java Script Code

```
<script>
var e = true;
$(function () {
    $("input:radio['name'='accept']").click(function () {
        radioClick();
    });

    $("#email").blur(function () {
        focusOutText();
    });
});

function focusOutText() {
    alert("Focus gone from TEXT");
    e = false;
};

function radioClick() {
    if (!e) {
        focusOutText();
    }
    alert("You clicked radio he he he..");
};
</script>
```

You can run here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efford Neeraj. The issue is, that your code doesn't work as expected, if the textbox still has the caret inside. In this case only focus lost gets fired.

Comment: Forget it. Everything's fine. I didn't get it. All good now :-)